# Where to disclose heuristic bypass

Tags: disclosure

There's one software, let's call it an anti-malware, that uses a heuristic to detect some types of attack. However there's a very simple to stay under its radar. Where may I report that kind of "exploit"? It does not require patching anything at runtime or any interaction with that software, so I don't see it really as a vulnerability, just something they've overlooked.
Where would I report that? Does that qualify for CVE?

Comment: You have not described a vulnerability or an exploit. You've described a weakness in the operation. Every single anti-malware detection process will have weaknesses. These do not qualify for CVEs.

Comment: @schroeder : thanks, you have confirmed my feeling and answered 50% of my question. I'm not even sure there's any common place to report weaknesses. Could you answer, including whether you're aware of such place?

Comment: The only people to report it to is the developer.

Comment: That's been done a while ago... If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not described a vulnerability or an exploit. You've described a weakness in the operation. Every single anti-malware detection process will have weaknesses. These do not qualify for CVEs.